# Using AMFPHP in an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, amfphp

I was wondering if there was any library or way of using AMFPHP with Ajax. I have a large class with methods ready and starting a new project where i use jQuery and instead of starting to separate pieces to php files, i would like (if there is any possibility) to use amfphp directly.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

`amfPHP` supports `JSON`, so yes, you can answer `jQuery` requests with `amfphp`.

See the `Pizza Example` in `amfPHP` for sample code.